# Upload audio url in twitter android

Tags: android, twitter

i am stuck in Twitter integration.I am done with image uploading through url but i am not able to upload audio or video url to twitter.
Any help is appreciated. Thanx guys
Twitter Code for uploading youtube url:

```
twitter.updateStatus("This is My Youtube url Test http://youtu.be/pfHxl46KyZM");
```

Logcat:

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Error creating status.
code - 189

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=12c480e1
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-12c480e1], statusCode=403, message=Error creating status., code=189, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.6-SNAPSHOT}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload video directly to Twitter - they simply don't support it.

Follow these steps.

1.Upload the video to a 3rd party service (like YouTube) 
2.Get the public URL of the uploaded video 
3.Add the URL to the status you send to Twitter - e.g. "Look at my Birtday video http://youtube.com/id"

If you want, you can add a thumbnail of the video as an image attachment

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Note sure but check if this helps you:-

```
String videoPath="video file path";

 TwitterSession twitterSession = new TwitterSession(MainActivity.this);

AccessToken accessToken = twitterSession.getAccessToken();

Values values = new Values();
 values.setSession(new Session());
TwitvidApi api = new TwitvidApi(values);
api.setSecureUrlEnabled(false);


Session session;

try {
session = api.authenticate(new TwitterAuthPack.Builder()
        .setConsumerKey(twitter_consumer_key)
        .setConsumerSecret(twitter_secret_key)
        .setOAuthToken(accessToken.getToken())
        .setOAuthTokenSecret(accessToken.getTokenSecret()).build());


api.getValues().setSession(session);

final UploadHelper helper = new UploadHelper(api);

File file = new File(videoPath);
TwitvidPost twitvidPost = new TwitvidPost.Builder().setFile(file)
        .setChunkSize(10485760).setMessage("Twitvid test")
        .setPostToTwitter(true).create();

try {

    if (helper.upload(twitvidPost)) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Posted on Twitter and Twitvid" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Posted on Twitter and Twitvid");
} else {

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Post failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

        .show();

Log.d("MainActivity", "Posted failed");

 }

} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();

         }

} catch (ApiException e1) {

e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: any example for same ?

Comment: i have used same code but some classes are removed like UploadHelper,UploadHelper

Answer (score 0):

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Put your Audio URL here &url="
                    + "https://www.google.com&hashtags=android,twitter";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

OR

```
// Consumer
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

// Access Token
AccessToken accessToken = null;
accessToken = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

// Posting Status
Status status = null;
try {
    status = twitter.updateStatus("YOUR_AUDIO_LINK");
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Successfully updated the URL: "
        + status.getText());
```

Comment: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/UpdateStatus.java us this.. you want this ?

Comment: 08-26 09:57:21.332: V/log_tag(5248): Pic Upload error403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).

Comment: this is what i got after upload status as audio/video url

Comment: @Richa please upload ur Logcat please so  that i can understand which probelm are you facing ?